# Contributions made via Charitable gift funds

Tags: contributions

My organization sometimes receives gifts from Donor Advised Gift Funds. We need to thank the individuals who are in the contacts table but also need to mention the source of the gift as being the Donor Advised fund. What is the best way to enter a contribution received in this way?

Answer (score 1):

This is specifically why soft credit types were introduced. Record the donation as coming from the fund and add a soft credit for the individual. Donor advised fund is one of the types available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Create an Financial type using the same name "Donor Advised Fund"

So you can select all the contribution using financial type Id "Donor Advised Fund" and you can send an email designed for them

Comment: Each "Donor Advised Fund" has a different name. For example, John and Jane Doe have a Donor advised fund with their name in the title. I presume you are not suggesting that I have a financial type for each fund. I could use the financial type field to signal that this is made thru the fund but then where to put the name of the fund?

Comment: if that is the case you can always use the contribution source - are all the contribution entered manually ??? - if not through online too you can set the source to "Donor Advised Fund" - which will help

Comment: Yes, all contributions are entered manually. We can put the name of the fund as you suggest in the Source but will this show up in a report?

Comment: yes - before running any report related to contribution please do select column "source" for report display - thanks